# Why is @Push not happening inside an iframe?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin 14 app that relies heavily on Push and works perfectly in normal browser tabs.
When the same URL is embedded in an iframe, the Push do not seem to happen. Nothing at all changes on the iframed page.  I am using the automatic Push mode.

I simply embedded the URL inside an iframe using https://www.iframe-generator.com/ and used their preview mode.  The page loads but no subsequent change happens.

Comment: Did you check the browser console?

Comment: Which transport are you using for Push?

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear here: _everything_ works as it should when
started in the `iframe` -- _except_ changes from the server side, that
should propagate via push are not?  E.g. if you interact with the page
inside the `iframe` changes appear (because the accumulated UI states is
now transported to the client)?

Comment: Zero clarity added... at least for me ;) I want to know, if push is **the only problem** you are facing -- as in **everything** else is working and the pushed state finally catches up once the user interacts with the framed application.

Comment: When including the page in the iframe, the display is correct, but further interactions don't take place (for example, clicking does not trigger the expected dialog).  Same in Chrome and Firefox.  If I use Firefox, there is a right-click option to open the frame in a new separate tab.  Then everything works.  It is possible to click on the page and the expected Vaadin dialog comes up.
So neither push nor click interactions appear to work.

Comment: If you save the following to a .html file, you will observe that the page opens correctly and shows an initial dialog.  Then it is impossible to close the dialog, and the server-induced push that would close the dialog after a few seconds never happens.
```
<iframe src="https://owlcms-demo.lerta.ca/displays/results" 
    style="border:0px #ffffff none;"
    name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" 
    height="800px" width="1200px"
    frameborder="1"
    marginheight="0px" 
    marginwidth="0px"  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```